# I can't disable scrolling (NOTHING WORKS, TRIED LOTS)

Tags: scroll

Here is a facetious cat site..

http://jsfiddle.net/Spunkgraffiti/ruxLs/embedded/result/

Go ahead and click on some blank space, stay clicked (mousedown), and drag your mouse down to the bottom of the window, it scroll's down! Every time!

The issue is that no matter what I do I can't disable scrolling when you click and drag to the bottom of the screen..

I have disabled the scroll wheels, tried to disable highlighting (cause I thought perhaps it was not "scrolling" per se but actually highlighting more and more content moving the page down), and tried a css disable of scrolling. Nothing works..

Overflow hidden doesn't help here either :/

How do I stop the scroll caused by clicking and dragging your mouse down to the bottom of the window (already fully expanded window).

I'm trying to write up a drag and drop bar at the bottom of the screen, but every time I drag a picture and try to drop it, the whole page moves.. I just want the whole page not to move when I begin to drag a picture..

Thank you everyone who takes the time to read this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ffy2x/5/

It is rock solid (doesn't scroll at all) on recent (as of this post's date) versions of Firefox, Chrome and WebKit in Qt.  Internet Explorer scrolls a bit then bounces back.  If it's for an embedded application using one of the first three, then this isn't a problem.

Comment: Maybe you'll find this interesting also: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/